# MFP 8.0 The runtime environment management bean is not registered

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are having `MFP8.0 Farm` configuration setup, there are 2 nodes running 
Now we are facing the issue in node1, it is giving error in `message.log`

> [10/31/17 6:00:38:504 CDT] 0000010a
>   com.worklight.common.util.jmx.MBeanConnectorFactory          I
>   Detected Liberty farm runtime [10/31/17 6:00:38:515 CDT] 0000010a
>   com.ibm.mfp.admin.services.v2.RuntimeService                 I No
>   mxbeans found [10/31/17 6:00:39:633 CDT] 0000011c
>   com.worklight.common.util.jmx.MBeanConnectorFactory          I
>   Detected Liberty farm runtime [10/31/17 6:00:39:935 CDT] 0000011c
>   com.worklight.common.util.jmx.MBeanConnectorFactory          I
>   Detected Liberty farm runtime [10/31/17 6:00:39:944 CDT] 0000011c
>   com.ibm.mfp.admin.services.v2.DiagnosticService              W
>   Exception when accessing Analytics JNDI properties for the runtime mfp
>   [10/31/17 6:00:43:553 CDT] 0000011f
>   com.worklight.common.util.jmx.MBeanConnectorFactory          I
>   Detected Liberty farm runtime [10/31/17 6:00:43:568 CDT] 0000011f
>   com.ibm.mfp.admin.services.v2.RuntimeService                 I No
>   mxbeans found [10/31/17 6:00:44:645 CDT] 0000012e
>   com.worklight.common.util.jmx.MBeanConnectorFactory          I
>   Detected Liberty farm runtime [10/31/17 6:00:44:686 CDT] 0000012e
>   com.worklight.common.util.jmx.MBeanConnectorFactory          I
>   Detected Liberty farm runtime [10/31/17 6:00:44:702 CDT] 0000012e
>   com.ibm.mfp.admin.services.v2.DiagnosticService              W
>   Exception when accessing Analytics JNDI properties for the runtime mfp
>   [10/31/17 6:00:48:605 CDT] 000000fe
>   com.worklight.common.util.jmx.MBeanConnectorFactory          I
>   Detected Liberty farm runtime [10/31/17 6:00:48:620 CDT] 000000fe
>   com.ibm.mfp.admin.services.v2.RuntimeService                 I No
>   mxbeans found

and when we we atop the node2 then this node starts working fine.

please let me know the solution

Comment: Provide code so users can help.

Comment: Has this been the case right from the first time you configured the farm. Or did it start some time - if so, what changed? 
The other query is if you shutdown both JVMs and then start only one , and then wait until its synced and only then start the next

Comment: No, we have done this setup 2 month back, but by last week we are getting this problem. and we haven't done any changes.
Yeah, i have tried to stop both the nodes, and after that i have started one by one node.. so upto 1 min both the nodes work fine.. but after that we will start getting the same error in one node. and in the console it shows unresponsive under server Farm status.

Comment: @TMichel  what code do u want ..?